# How is an .xib file translated to a UI element?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, xib

From what I understand, MainMenu.xib contains XML that is used to create the main menu for an application. My question is, how is this file loaded, read, and used to create the main menu? Can anyone help me to understand the inner workings of the code that translates MainMenu.xib into the actual main menu seen in the UI?

Here is my understanding of the process so far.

1. MainMenu.xib is compiled into an .nib
2. The .nib is loaded into a UINib object.
3. From here, the UINib object is somehow used to create the Main Menu.

This is the part I am confused about. How exactly is the UINib object used to create the Main Menu?

Comment: This question is too broad to be asking on StackOverflow

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle Okay, thanks for the heads up! Any suggestions on how I could make it more specific so that it's within StackOverflow guidelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine this the other way around: you have a live view hierarchy in memory, in your running application. Now you want to allow the program to be terminated while saving the state of the UI. How would you do that? You would somehow write all the important properties of the live views to disk; some kind of serialization and archiving process.

That's all a nib is: it's an archive of a bunch of objects that happen to be views. (It encodes the "base" state of the views, of course, before any user interaction.) A xib, as you correctly noted, is an XML rendering of that archive, which makes it cooperate better with version control.

If you take a look at the XML of a xib in Xcode, you'll see that it consists of entries like this:

```
<tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" rowHeight="161" id="KGk-i7-Jjw" customClass="LeakInfoStepsCell" customModule="LookoutEmailLeakAlert" customModuleProvider="target">
        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="170"/>
        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
...
```

Just a listing of various properties on the view and the values they should have when the nib is unarchived. So when you load a UINib, it's reading those properties and creating view objects, just as you might do manually in code, or as you would do for your own object via `NSCoding`.

Comment: Thank you! this actually helps a lot. I had this creeping thought that there was some sort of "magic" behind the UINib class, but I see that's not really the case. This helps quite a bit - much appreciated :)

Comment: I admit that this is based on reasoning, not actually having seen UINib code, but I don't believe there's any real magic involved. Glad I could help.

Comment: Well that reasoning makes a lot of sense to me! Also, one more question - say I wanted to read in MainMenu.xib and create the main menu manually (that is, define my own "file," "view," etc. options in the .xib, parse the .xib, and then create the Main Menu from this .xib). I understand now how I would read in and parse the data in MainMenu.xib, but do you have any hints on how I would create the main menu from there?

Comment: To clarify, I understand how this would work if, say, I had a subclass of UIView called SomeView, and I were reading in an .xib file that described UI elements that were instances of SomeView (I would just parse the .xib and create instances of SomeView as specified). My question is specifically with regards to how the main menu is created. Is the main menu also represented using subclasses of UIView, or is there something special that is done? Apologies if this is poor question, just looking for some hints to point me in the right direction! :)

Comment: There's no UIView on OS X -- there's NSView -- and there's not usually a "MainMenu" xib in iOS, so I'm a little confused what you're asking about. But in a default MainMenu.xib created by Xcode for an OS X project, you can see a `menu` object, which represents an instance of `NSMenu`, which is the menu bar. You add NSMenuItems to it, but you can do that in code or via Interface Builder. You don't need to re-invent NSNib.